# Using Arrays for loops in SAS

Tags: sas

I have this dataset

```
    DATA Problem3;
    INPUT name $ Smoke_Tobacco $ Drink_Alcohol $ Take_Illegal_Drugs $ Drink_Soda $;
DATALINES;
    Tom yes no no yes
    Harry Yes Yes Yes No
    Jim No No No Yes
    Bob Yes No No Yes
    Andy No Yes No Yes
    Cody yes no no no
    Ed Yes no no yes
    Greg no Yes no No
    Dave Yes No Yes no
;
RUN;
```

And I want to use loops to change all "yes" responses to "Yes" and all "no" responses to "No".

My idea is to use arrays for this such as what is shown in the Little SAS workbook

```
DATA songs;    
    INFILE 'c:\MyRawData\KBRK.dat';    
    INPUT City $ 1-15 Age wj kt tr filp ttr;    
    ARRAY song (5) wj kt tr filp ttr;    
    DO i = 1 TO 5;       
        IF song(i) = 9 THEN song(i) = .;    
    END;
Run;
```

Which replaces "9" with ".". So I edit my code to

```
    DATA Problem3;
    INPUT name $ Smoke_Tobacco $ Drink_Alcohol $ Take_Illegal_Drugs $ Drink_Soda $;
DATALINES;
    Tom yes no no yes
    Harry Yes Yes Yes No
    Jim No No No Yes
    Bob Yes No No Yes
    Andy No Yes No Yes
    Cody yes no no no
    Ed Yes no no yes
    Greg no Yes no No
    Dave Yes No Yes no
;
    ARRAY Answer (4) Smoke_Tobacco Drink_Alcohol Take_Illegal_Drugs Drink_Soda;
    DO i=1 TO 9;
        IF Answer(i) = 'yes' THEN Answer(i)= 'Yes';
        ELSE IF Answer(i) = 'no' THEN Answer(i)= 'No';
    END;

RUN;
```

But I get errors saying that the lines in my addition are either not valid or out of order. How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare your array as a character, so add the $ into the array declaration
2. Just apply PROPCASE to the variables which will standardize all to have the first letter as a capital.
3. Why are you looping to 9, when you only have 4 items?
4. You have to put the array statements BEFORE the datalines. Nothing after the data is processed.

   ```
   DATA Problem3;
   INPUT name $ Smoke_Tobacco $ Drink_Alcohol $ Take_Illegal_Drugs $ Drink_Soda $;

   ARRAY Answer (4) $3. Smoke_Tobacco Drink_Alcohol Take_Illegal_Drugs Drink_Soda;
       DO i=1 TO 4;
           answer(i)=propcase(answer(i));
       END;
   DATALINES;
   Tom yes no no yes
   Harry Yes Yes Yes No
   Jim No No No Yes
   Bob Yes No No Yes
   Andy No Yes No Yes
   Cody yes no no no
   Ed Yes no no yes
   Greg no Yes no No
   Dave Yes No Yes no
   ;


   RUN;
   ```

Comment: 1. Wasn't aware that was a requirement,

2. Wasn't aware that was an option either

3. I mistook rows for items

4. I wasn't sure where to put it so I was trying to follow how the book placed it.

Thank you for the help. The only way I learn the coding is by making mistakes such as these so this helped me learn a lot.

Comment: You only need to add `$` in the `ARRAY` statement if you are using the `ARRAY` statement to create **new** variables.  In that case you should also add the length that you want the new variables to have.

Comment: @Tom, Thanks, you're correct, as always :).  I prefer to add it in always as best practice otherwise I forgot to half the time. Avoids errors in the long run. The code did use $3, as you advised.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot add statements after the end of the data step!**

Just move your new statement to before the `DATALINES;` statement that marks the end of your data step and the beginning of your in-line data.  Also make sure the upper bound on your `do` loop matches the size of your array.  Let SAS figure that out for you.  `do i=1 TO dim(answer);`

This is the second confusion along these lines that I have seen recently? I wonder if it is caused by people reflexively adding an extra `run;` statement after the end of their data steps that use in-line data?  That extra `run;` is not needed and becomes a new empty step,  not part of the original data step.